# why I cannot change the value in loop of `set<set<int>>`

Tags: c++

Here is the minimum function of my question:

```
void solve(void)
{
    set<set<int> > test;
    for(set<set<int> >::iterator it = test.begin(); it != test.end(); ++it) {
        // (*it)'s type is set<int> right? but why I cannot insert a int into this?
        it -> insert(1);
    }
}
```

The compiler tell me that `no matching function for call to 'std::set<int>::insert(int) const'`.

It really confuse me that why it do not use `std::set<int>::insert(int)` without the `const`? How can I do this? Can I make it really?

```
*** first edited ***
```

I know that I can erase an element like `it = test.erase(it)` and I also know that I can use `test.insert(<a set<int> value>)`, so is it possible to insert firstly and then delete the original element? but it looks troublesome right?

```
*** seconed edited ***
```

About the use-case: Before I know the Disjoint-set data structure, I want to slove its problem, so I need to deal with the `set<int> type data` in `set<set<int>> type data`. It upset me that I find I cannot change the inner `set` in the loop so I cannot union those inner sets - (or maybe I can, I try to put those elements of inner set's value into a temp `set` and then I remove the original `set`s, then I insert the temp `set` into `set<set>`. *BUT* it does look ugly). So I know to make it but I do not know why the iterators are `const`, and I also want t know a better way to deal with `set`s in `set`.

```
*** third edited ***
```

Thank you @anurag-dhadse for pointing the grammar error.

Thanks.

Comment: `std::set::iterator` is a constant iterator

Comment: You cannot chage elements of `std::set`, they are `const`.

Comment: What is the use-case? What is the actual problem you need to solve? Why do you think a set of sets would be a good solution?

Comment: As for *why* you can't modify the outer set, it's because sets are ordered, but they are only ordered when a key is added. Once a key is added, any attempt to modify it would change the ordering, and sets aren't designed that way, so the keys are constant.

Comment: @TonyDelroy Hello, I do think your comment is good enough to be an answer for this question. Would you like to post it as an answer please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `it->insert(1)` attempts to change a `set<int>` inside the outer `set<set<int>>`, and in so doing might change the position in which `*it` should be stored in the outer `set`, which would breach the [class invariants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_invariant) by not keeping the elements sorted. To avoid that, the outer `set` only gives `it` `const` access to the `set<int>` elements

If you want to modify a `set<int>` element, you need to [`extract`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/extract) it from the outer `set`, modify it, then `insert` it back wherever it should now go.

Comment: One more words, the method `extract` is supposed after `C++17` and these is a [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62852379/13031497) about how to use it in a loop, which its question is also asked by me. I think change the element in a ordering contain is not a good idea, but in my opinion it will be helpful to know it.

Answer (score 1):

You realize that if you insert many sets inside an "outer" set, those inner sets will be placed in lexicographical order:

```
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main () {

 set A1 = {2, 7};
 set A2 = {1, 8, 3, 4};
 set A3 = {1, 4, 3};

 set<set<int>> set_of_sets;
 set_of_sets.insert(A1);
 set_of_sets.insert(A2);
 set_of_sets.insert(A3);

 for ( auto& inner_set : set_of_sets ) {
     std::cout << "[ " ;
     for ( auto &element :  inner_set ) {
         std::cout << element << " ";
     }
     std::cout << "]\n";
 }
}
```

Will produce the following response:

```
[ 1 3 4 ]
[ 1 3 4 8 ]
[ 2 7 ]
```

They changed the order, not only the integers inside each set, but A1 was swapped by A3 (following lexicographical order )

https://godbolt.org/z/nacxrn

If you insert `1` to each set, the [1 3 4] will not change, the [1 3 4 8] will also not change, but [2 7] will become [1 2 7] wich means that A1 should be swappped by A3 again since [1 2 7] < [1 3 4], therefore C++ does not allow you to change the position of the inner sets inside the outer set during iteration ( by making iterators const ).

So, it´s not clear why you are using a set.
it´s easy ( for many applications ) just use a vector of sets so you can change them freely:

```
    vector<set<int> > test { A1, A2, A3 } ;
    for(auto& s : test ) {
        s.insert(1); /// inserting 1 in all sets
    }
```

https://godbolt.org/z/WMvse9

Comment: Thanks a lot! the elements in set should have a method named `less` for ordering. I like you answer and the way to use vector is really a good idea for my usage. I am sorry that I cannot accept two answers. Happy to look you help more and more persons.