# unexpend for-loop result after change the third part of for-loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, c++17, extract

When I use `for-loop` in my source file, I get a unexpend result. Here is the minimum source file (I hide the head of file and the function of `print_set`):

```cpp
// the main function
int main(void) {
    set<int> test{3, 5};
    print_set(test);

    for (auto it = test.begin(); it != test.end();) {
        auto node = test.extract(it);
        ++it;
    }
    print_set(test);
}
```

Then I use command to compile and run:

```sh
$ g++ --version
g++ (Dedian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0
... (not very important infomation for this question)
$ g++ -std=c++17 temp.cpp
$ ./a.out
[ 3 5 ]
[ ]
```

Now all thing goes well but after I change the `for-loop` part to this (I replace `++it` to the third part of `for-loop`'s head):

```cpp
    for (auto it = test.begin(); it != test.end(); ++it) {
        auto node = test.extract(it);
    }
```

Now the result is:

```sh
$ ./a.out
[ 3 5 ]
zsh: segmentation fault (core dumped) ./a.out
```

`Zsh` is the Linux shell that I am using that is not very important infomation. After view some web pages about `for-loop` like [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for), etc., I still do not know why? Is it a bug? Why these are not equal and have two different results? Because the method `extract`? But why can the first part can run?

Thanks.

Comment: `auto node = test.extract(it);` I think `it` is invalidated here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`std::set<T>::extract()` documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/extract):

> Extracting a node invalidates the iterators to the extracted element.

After the call to `test.extract(it)`, the iterator `it` is no longer valid.  Even incrementing it or comparing it to another iterator are not defined operations.  The only safe things you can do to `it` after extraction are:

- Let it be destructed.
- Assign a valid iterator to it.

Anything else causes undefined behavior, therefore both code examples in your question invoke undefined behavior.  Asking why one does something different than the other is a meaningless question.  They might each do something different each time the program is run -- including what you wanted the code to do!

**Undefined behavior cannot be reasoned about and it is almost always a waste of time trying to do so.**

To fix the code, you would need to copy the iterator, increment the original, then extract the copy.  This is exactly what the post-increment operator does:

```
for (auto it = test.begin(); it != test.end();) {
    auto node = test.extract(it++);
}
```

In this example, `it` is mutated *before* extraction happens.  This example has well-defined behavior, and will extract each element in the set one by one.